# Sharing stylesheet files between docker containers

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, stylesheet

There is a symfony 5 php application that runs in a docker container. I do not mount source data into the running container, instead the Dockerfile copies the deployed source code into the image that is delivered to several customers.

Now I need a second container that contains the css and javascript files the php app needs at runtime. Every client needs custom stylesheets so I have to separate the basic application and the stylesheets. The application container and the stylesheet container share a named volume that contains the stylesheets.

Problem: When I update the sytlesheets and deploy a new stylesheet container, I have to remove the named volume before I update the stylesheet container at my clients server. Otherwise the volume always contains the old version of the sytlesheets.

Is there a better way to share data between two interdependent containers or separate application data and stylesheets?

Comment: If the stylesheets differ for each client, how does the PHP container know which stylesheets to load?  Also, I'm not trying to be pejorative, but this has a pretty big code smell.  My knee-jerk reaction is to say to make a build per customer.  As part of that build do the normal CSS/JS building steps (concatenate, transpile, uglify, minify, hash for cache busting, etc.).  Anyway, a shared volume is definitely not a scalable solution.  If you absolutely have to share CSS/JS for some reason, you could use a CDN, NFS, or cloud object storage like S3.

Comment: There will be only one stylesheet container on every clients system. The advantage with that scenario is that I only must update the main-source-container in case there will be a newer version, without building a custom image (with different stylesheets) for ever customer. But you are right, using a volume is not the solution here.

Comment: So how does each main-source container know which stylesheets to load if the stylesheets differ from client to client?

Comment: The css files (the custom theme) always have the same filenames. So the main-source-container has to look into a specific directory for a specific file / files. Every client system has one main-source container and one stylesheet-container with always the same filenames inside but different stylesheet contents.

Comment: With that paradigm there are obvious caching issues.  If you update a stylesheet but don't change the name then the old stylesheet will be cached by your users' browsers.  Generally CSS is built, and as part of that build process the file name is changed such that it contains a hash of the contents.  Again, this whole thing has a pretty big code smell.